Whis is this x86_64 AT&T assembly failing, i think foo: is the culprit?
Here is the assembly, I am using Windows 11.
Assembling: as .\test.S -o test.out
Linking: ld -o test.exe -subsys=console test.out -L "C:\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" -lmsvcrt
When i run the program a garbage exit code is thrown...
I think the foo function is the culprit.
Even when i remove call foo, it gives random exit code.
    ;#; This file was generated by the MZ compiler.
    .section .data
b:  .space  8
a:  .space  8
    .section .text
foo:
    push    %rbp
    mov     %rsp,       %rbp
    sub     $32,        %rsp
    add     $32,        %rsp
    pop     %rbp
    ret     

    .global _start
_start:
    push    %rbp
    mov     %rsp,       %rbp
    sub     $32,        %rsp
    lea     a(%rip),    %rax
    movq    $420,       (%rax)
    lea     b(%rip),    %rax
    movq    $42,        (%rax)
    mov     $10,        %rcx
    mov     $3,         %rdx
    call    foo
    add     $32,        %rsp
    pop     %rbp
    movq    $0,         %rax
    ret     


How do you examine the exit code?

@Jester First i run the exe and the use echo %errorlevel% to see the exit code of last executed process

You need to specify -e _start otherwise apparently the entry point will be at the beginning of the code which happens to be your foo and that does not return anything in particular.

Isn't that the entry point by default ??

Not on windows, no. There are a couple of symbols ld looks for, but the default is mainCRTStartup

You might also experiment with ExitProcess, as the official way to terminate a process under Windows.

Using ret from the program entry point may not work as the program entry point is not necessarily “called” as a function.

If GNU Binutils ld doesn't find the symbol it's looking for and makes the entry point the start of the .text section, it prints a warning.  (At least on GNU/Linux, where it does look for _start, the warning is warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000).  You should have gotten a warning like that if that was the problem.

For whatever reason, the source code says: /* No entry has been specified.  Look for the default entry, but don't warn if we don't find it.  */
